# Mismatching pg_dump on MacOS X

Tags: macos, postgresql

Locally, it appears that I have Postgresql 9.2.4 installed.  I am guessing based off the last error message I received that I do not have the latest version:

```
pg_dump: server version: 9.3.1; pg_dump version: 9.2.4
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

On other posts here, what was told to do was to add the following the the .profile and then run the command:

```
export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
. ~/.profile
```

which did not work.

2 weeks ago, I installed Postgresql with the simple command:

```
brew install postgresql
```

and that gave me the version I currently have.  It appears as I don't have the latest version then.

How can I a) upgrade to 9.3.1 (which is what the server version looks to be) or b) do one of these fixes like the one I attempted above which did not work.

I am very new to Postgresql so a step by step would be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 8):

```
brew upgrade postgresql
brew link --overwrite postgresql
```

Comment: in my case I did `brew link --overwrite postgresql@15`

Answer (score 6):

Solved by adding this at the end of my `~/.bash_profile` ( or `~/.zshrc` for zsh)

```
export PG_DUMP="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin/"
PATH=$PG_DUMP:$PATH
```

Don't forget to run (for bash shell)

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

or (for zsh)

```
$ source ~/.zshrc
```

You can check the path of `pg_dump` by running

```
$ which pg_dump
 ==> /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin//pg_dump
```

- MacOS Mojave (10.14.2)
- Postgres.app (2.1.5)
- PostgreSQL 9.6

Comment: `source ~/.bash_profile` assumes user is using bash shell and not for example `zsh`

Answer (score 0):

I use MacOS 13.6. I have installed several versions and after removing and reinstalling some of them, got error:

```
pg_dump: error: aborting because of server version mismatch
pg_dump: detail: server version: 16.1; pg_dump version: 15.3
```

I added version 16 bin path to my fishell to solve the problem

```
fish_add_path /Library/PostgreSQL/16/bin
```

Answer (score -1):

There are upgrade instructions you have to follow between Postgresql 9.2 and 9.3...

1. launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
2. mv /usr/local/var/postgres /usr/local/var/postgres92
3. brew update
4. brew upgrade postgresql
5. initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8
6. pg_upgrade -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.4/bin -B /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.1/bin -d /usr/local/var/postgres92 -D /usr/local/var/postgres
7. launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist

Comment: I do not have the first file you are speaking about.  All I have for homebrew in this folder is a redis file, and when I simply run 'brew upgrade postgresql' it says postgresql-9.2.4 already installed

Comment: Then skip that step and proceed to the others.  Use common sense.  The main idea is that you have to run the `pg_upgrade` step between the old and new database binaries.

Comment: You'll have to upgrade homebrew as well, I'll add the additional step for that.

Comment: The asker already runs a 9.3.1 server according to the error message, so all this makes no sense.

Comment: I now have downloaded 9.3.2, great!  Step 5 is giving me an error saying the directory exists.

Comment: again, then don't worry about it.  Line 7 is the important one.

Comment: @DanielVérité Dude, I don't make the rules, I only live with them.  This is what you have to do to upgrade PostGresql on OSX.  I had to do it too.

Comment: The error message says: `pg_dump: server version: 9.3.1`. I'm not saying your instructions to upgrade from 9.2.x are wrong, my point is they don't apply because he's not running 9.2.x.

Comment: reading _between the lines_ here, my understanding is he was _trying_ to upgrade and now he's getting that error.  Which is _exactly_ what the OP just asked for in his update.  But yes, I understand your original statement @DanielVérité ... I always try to _infer_ what the OP means (of course, I'm not _always_ right).